# "Hide" Users in Active Directory Search

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is it possible to "hide" users when searching Active Directory Users and Computers? For example, if I do not want administrative accounts or groups appearing in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways i know of:

1. be specific when using the search dialog i.e full name or first name or surname
2. create a query instead where you can specify whatever you want to omit or include.